# Como enviar variáveis via ajax/php

Tags: php, javascript

Caros preciso enviar mais de uma variável via ajax/php, efetuei alguns testes sem sucesso, como devo proceder?

PHP (este funciona mas não consigo inserir outra variável)

```
$("#colPasta").focus(function(){
    var val = new Array();
    $('.check:checked').each(function(){
        val.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:'colPasta.php',
        type:'GET',
        data:'col=<?php print $colar; ?>',
        success:function(data){
            $('.exibeColPasta').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Já tentei usar o seguinte comando PHP sem sucesso.

```
data:{ 'col'= <?php echo $colar; ?>, 'ovo'= <?php echo $ovo; ?>},
```

Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Consegui aplicar mais de uma variável para envio, porém ainda sem sucesso para arrays

data:{col:'<?php print $colar; ?>',mov:'<?php print $colar2; ?>'},

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou assim?

```
 var dadosajax = {
    'campo1' : 'valor',
    'campo2' : 'valor'
}
```

e depois pra recuperar

```
$campo1 = $_REQUEST['campo1'];
$campo2 = $_REQUEST['campo2'];
```

e o ajax ficaria assim...

```
 pageurl = 'php/finalizou.php';
$.ajax({
    url: pageurl,
    data: dadosajax,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
    },
    success: function(result)
    { 
        if($.trim(result) == '1')
        {
            console.log('certo')
        }
        //se foi um erro
        else
        {
           console.log('erro')
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Então Yuri, no caso eu preciso enviar 3 arrays separados, por isso de enviar mais de uma variável.

Comment: vou aplicar um array multidimensional e tratar internamente, não é a melhor solução mas creio que sirva para o momento.

Comment: apesar de enviar um multidimensional ele recebe como uma string :(

Comment: Sim pois a gente utilizou no exemplo string 'string', mas você pode colocar qualquer valor, por exemplo pegar o valor de um input. $('#inputid').attr('value');

Answer (score 2):

É assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'colPasta.php',
    type:'GET',
    data: { col: <?php print $colar; ?>, col_2: <?php print $colar2; ?>, col3: <?php print $colar3; ?> }
    success:function(data){
        $('.exibeColPasta').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Então Zoom, assim no meu código não consegui resgatar, já ví algumas aplicações assim mas acho que eu estou fazendo algo errado, mesmo assim vlw.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sempre sou a favor de práticas que facilitam a visualização do código.

Então, nesse caso tendo em vista as variáveis "soltas" `$ovo` e `$colar`, eu usaria a função `compact` para transformar uma lista de variáveis em `array` e codificaria para `json`, para ficar mais fácil a passagem de parâmetros para data.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'colPasta.php',
    type:'GET',
    data: <?php echo json_encode(compact('colar', 'ovo')) ?>,
    success:function(data){
        $('.exibeColPasta').html(data);
    }
});
```

Então `echo json_encode(compact('colar', 'ovo'))` retornaria a seguinte string JSON:

```
{"ovo" : "valor da variável $ovo", "colar" : "valor da variável $colar"}
```

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância Wallace mas para recuperar o json em ajax é normal ou tem alguma instrução antes?

Comment: Recuperar você diz a resposta ou o "compact" feito na pergunta?

Comment: Recuperar digo ... $var = $_request['ovo'];

Comment: nao uses o request usa  get ou post

Answer (score 1):

boas aqui tens

o pesquisa é um formulario o accao é o que envio podes enviar mais se quiseres

```
    var accao = {"action": "enviadados"};
var data = $("#pesquisa").serialize() + "&" + $.param(accao);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ".php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,success: function (data) {} });
```